# jquery pattern for multiple continuous ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, design-patterns

I have a for each loop with an array, for each element in the array I need to retrieve data from the server so I will make an ajax request per element and store the result in another array, I need to know when the last element in the array has been processed so I can display the data, is there a pattern or how could I do this without over complicating things which I think is what I'm doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    arrayLength = array.length,
    completed = 0;
```

Then, in the callbacks of your XHR,

```
if (completed == arrayLength) {
   // All of them have finished.
}

completed++;
```

Alternatively, you state that you are adding the things to a new array. Assuming that when finished the arrays will be of equal length, you can change the check in the callback to `(startArray.length == newArray.length)`.

Also, keep in mind if you are making XHR (assuming asynchronous) in a loop, they will all be trying to request at roughly the same time (I think), which may be an issue with performance. Consider writing a function which is called again on each individual request's callback, so the XHRs are made one at a time. Increment a counter so you can subscript the next array element in each call.

Answer (score 1):

A continuation passing library that has a "parallel" mode will abstract this nicely. I'm using [JooseX-CPS](https://github.com/SamuraiJack/JooseX-CPS), also see its [tutorial](http://joose.it/blog/2011/02/14/joosex-cps-tutorial-part-i/).

Answer (score 0):

For each on success you hit, count up the successful results and then trigger an event.

For example:

```
var successfulReturns= 0; 
$.ajax({ 
    url:"", 
    success: function() { 
        successfulReturns++; 
        $(document).trigger("myapp.loadedComplete"); 
    }
});
```

and then listen for your event

```
$(document).bind("myapp.loadedComplete", function() {  } );
```

This lets you test the completion somewhere outside of the loop.